# Running multiple Python Scripts from one file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have 3 scripts that needs to be executed. Two of them have continuous loop and will never stop runing as long as sensors are sending the data, and 3rd script will run only once every hour.

So lets say i have them like this:

sensorscript1
sensorscript2
Export

What would be the best method to create one single file to run this process?
Would using threading be the best way to go in this case?

```
import sensorscript1, sensorscript2
from threading import Thread
```

Or would Flask app be better suited for this?
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another approach to do this **if you want each script to run in a new window & maybe look at the logs on it.**

You could run one script that calls the other scripts using a `subprocess` call.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("start cmd /K python sensorscript1.py", shell=True) 
                         # this opens the script1.py file in a new console window (shell=True)
subprocess.call("start cmd /K python sensorscript2.py", shell=True)
subprocess.call("start cmd /K python Export.py", shell=True)
```

Or alternatively you can run Export & call the other two scripts from it - it's upto you to decide how it runs best for you.

Comment: I think it might be easier for me to run your solution ParvBanks. I am going to try it.

Comment: Great! Do let me know how it goes... I've used it in a project myself so I know it works.
The advantage is that you're able to monitor the logs in each window separately.

Answer (score 0):

Use PyThreads, a new threading library for python. https://github.com/Narasimha1997/PyThreads, this makes running threads much more easier.

For example you have 3 script files, f1, f2 and f3, write functions in all these 3 files as threads using PyThreads

Example : 
File -1

```
from pythreads import pythread
@pythread
def fun1() : 
  #some logic
  pass
```

File -2:

```
from pythreads import pythread

@pythread
def fun2():
   #some logic
   pass
```

Now in main file import them

```
from file1 import fun1
from file2 import fun2

#call these functions, because of @pythreads, they start behaving like threads
fun1()
fun2()

#your function 3
def fun3():
  #some logic 
  pass

#call it here
if __name__ == "__main__" :
   fun3()
```

PS: I wrote PyThreads to make thread usage easier in python

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. But how do i install PyThreads since its not published yet?

Comment: `fun1()` and `fun2()` should still be called in `main`.

Comment: Just add it in your project folder , and yeah you can call it from main also

Comment: Disclaimer: This is a library he wrote

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much got it

```
import sensorscript1, sensorscript2
from threading import Thread

t1 = Thread(target=sensorscript1, args=(arg1, arg2))
t2 = Thread(target=sensorscript2, args=(arg,))

t1.run()
t2.run()
```

Note the args parameter is only needed if you are passing arguments to the function. Also note the extra comma. This is because the args parameter requires a Tuple